# .draggable('destroy') is Generating a Type Error

Tags: jquery-ui

I have an image wrapped in a draggable div#imgWrapper.  I want to drop div#imgWrapper into a div#content, which is full of text.   div#imgWrapper is given a float:left style by the drop code so the text in div#content flows around the inserted div#imgWrapper after the drop. See http://jsfiddle.net/upcKw/1.

I don't want to let the user drag div#imgWrapper out of div#content once it's been dropped so I also have the drop code destroy the draggability of div#imgWrapper:

```
 ui.draggable.draggable('destroy');
```

This all works fine, except that the destroy call generates an error that I see with console.log:

[image]

Does anyone know what's causing this and how I can get rid of it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to disable the draggable. This also won't allow the user to drag the image again but - as it seems - this doesn't throw an error.

```
ui.draggable.draggable('disable').css('opacity', '1');
```

Updated <kbd>[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SirDerpington/upcKw/4/)</kbd>

I just added the `.css('opacity', '1')` because normally there would be a lower opacity to indicate the disabled draggable.
This results in the same as your desired behaviour. But this of course doesn't remove the draggable property completely.

Comment: Thanks.  That works fine.  I had tried disable but I wasn't sure what to do about the faded image it left and what other funny state that might imply.  But as you showed, I guess I can just override it with opacity 1 and move on.

Answer (score 0):

This is well known jQueryUI bug, not fixed for ages.

Comment: Thanks.  So I can ignore it?